# Inject a Class<T> with GIN

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection, guice, gwt-gin

Is there a way to inject a class type `Class<T>` in gin? I can't seem to get it working, for example:

```java
class GenericFoo<T> {

  private final Class<T> klass;

  @Inject
  public GenericFoo(Class<T> klass) {
    this.klass = klass;
  }
}

class Bar { }
```

with an instance injected somewhere:

```
..
@Inject
GenericFoo<Bar> instance;
..
```

and a GinModule containing something along the lines of:

```java
bind(new TypeLiteral<Class<Bar>>() {}).to(Bar.class);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. Reflection is forbidden on the client side, so GIN for dependency injection is using deffered binding. It means that during the compilation, GWT generates target implementations which are unknow in your case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you misunderstood me, made an edit to clarify. I don't need reflection, just want to bind Class<Foo> to Foo.getClass().

Answer (score 3):

If this were regular Guice (as opposed to Gin), you could do:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Class<Bar>>(){}).toInstance(Bar.class);
```

But Gin doesn't support `.toInstance(...)` bindings. Instead, you should be able to use a `Provider` or an `@Provides` method, like:

```
@Provides
Class<Bar> providesBarClass() {
  return Bar.class;
}
```