# Use GIN to inject a Generics factory of ListEditor

Tags: gwt, generics, guice, gwt-gin, gwt-editors

I've written a factory able to create ListEditor of any type:

```
public interface ListEditorFactory<T, E extends Editor<T>> {
    ListEditor<T, E> create(InsertPanel panel);
}
```

And its implementation:

```
public class ListEditorFactoryImpl<T, E extends Editor<T> & IsWidget> implements ListEditorFactory<T, E> {
    private final Provider<E> editorProvider;

    @Inject
    public ListEditorFactoryImpl(Provider<E> editorProvider) {
        this.editorProvider = editorProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public ListEditor<T, E> create(final InsertPanel panel) {
        return ListEditor.of(new EditorSource<E>() {
            @Override
            public E create(int index) {
                final E e = editorProvider.get();
                panel.add(e.asWidget());
                return e;
            }

            @Override
            public void dispose(E e) {
                e.asWidget().removeFromParent();
            }

            @Override
            public void setIndex(E editor, int index) {
                panel.insert(editor.asWidget(), index);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It works very well if I instantiate directly the factory with a Provider injected by Gin:

```
ListEditor<NoteDTO, CharacterNoteScreen> notesEditor;
@Inject @UiField(provided = true) FlowPanel notePanel;

@Inject
protected void init(Provider<CharacterNoteScreen> characterNoteProvider) {
    final ListEditorFactory<NoteDTO, CharacterNoteScreen> listEditorFactory = new ListEditorFactoryImpl<NoteDTO, CharacterNoteScreen>(characterNoteProvider);
    notesEditor = listEditorFactory.create(notePanel);
```

But if I want to inject the whole ListEditorFactory like this:

```
@Inject
protected void init(ListEditorFactory<NoteDTO, CharacterNoteScreen> listEditorFactory) {
    notesEditor = listEditorFactory.create(notePanel);
```

Gin complains with a simple `bind(ListEditorFactory.class).to(ListEditorFactoryImpl.class);` binding:

```
[ERROR] Generator 'com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'net.test.client.MyGinjector'
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
1) javax.inject.Provider<E> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
```

I tried with `bind(new TypeLiteral<ListEditorFactory<?, ?>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<ListEditorFactoryImpl<?, ?>>() {});` but got an

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a Class, ParameterizedType, or GenericArrayType, but <?> is of type com.google.inject.internal.MoreTypes$WildcardTypeImpl
```

The binding `bind(new TypeLiteral<ListEditorFactory<NoteDTO, CharacterNoteScreen>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<ListEditorFactoryImpl<NoteDTO, CharacterNoteScreen>>() {});` is working but the generic factory loses a lot of its interest.

Do you know a generic way to declare this binding?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by getting rid of the `ListEditorFactory` interface, no more need to declare binding in the gin module.

I can directly inject the implementation without any problem:

```
@Inject
protected void init(ListEditorFactoryImpl<NoteDTO, CharacterNoteScreen> listEditorFactory) {
    notesEditor = listEditorFactory.create(notePanel);
```

If gin is able to inject this, I see no reason it can't inject it trough an interface but wrong binding declaration.

So even if I'm happy with my solution I let the question open because it might be a way to declare the binding.

Comment: According to [Inject a Class<T> with GIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093274/inject-a-classt-with-gin) Gin can't inject generics with wildcard type because it does all its work at compile time where effective type is unknown. I still don't understand how it's working without binding declaration, I imagine there is the same problem. Anyway I accept this answer because it seems there is no better solution.